# How to install pre-requisites for Hyperledger Composer on Windows10

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, hyperledger-composer

I am following the tutorial for Hyperledger Composer.  I'm trying to install the pre-requisites for the Composer as outlined here:
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/installing-prereqs.html

The instructions are only provided for Ubuntu or Mac, and I have Win10 machine with Docker 17.12.x

So I got Ubuntu 16.04 docker image, added curl.   I got the prereqs-ubuntu.sh script, I login as blockchain user, and run the script, but I get this error:

```
#Updating package lists 
-sudo apt-add-repository:  command not found
```

Is it even possible to install Hperledger Composer on a Windows 10 machine?!

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible to install Hyperledger Composer on windows which includes the Windows Subsystem for Linux and other environments like MinGW that simulate a linux environment. This platform is not supported at this time. I recommend you use a hypervisor such as VirtualBox or if you are using Windows 10 Professional, the built in Hyper-V support to run a Linux virtual machine where you can install Hyperledger Composer. Also we recommend using ubuntu 16.04 as this is the level we test with most.

Comment: Can VirtualBox be run in 32 bit mode?  To enable 64bit I had to turn Off Hyper-V and enable virtualization in BIOS settings at startup.  When I do that Docker no longer works.... :(

Comment: Looks like I have Hyper-V on my machine, so maybe that's a better way.